# Ruby on Rails get route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm totally new on Ruby, I need to create route get which will write dynamically text = "About Us"

`about.html.erb` code:

```
<h1><%= @title %></h1>
```

`index.html.erb` code:

```
<h1>Index</h1>
```

Routes code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'posts#index' 

  get 'about' => 'pages#about'

end
```

In the folder controllers I have defined `pages_controller.rb` and `posts_controller.rb`,`pages` with simple function `about` and `posts` with function `index`

In the folder views/pages I have `about.html.erb` and views/posts `index.html.erb`

The problem is when I run it, it writes message only from index and not from `about.html.erb`

Rake routes message:

```
$ rake routes
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         posts#index
    about GET    /about(.:format)          pages#about
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

Comment: What error do you receive from `/about`? Try to run `rake routes`, what it shows?

Comment: @IlyaLavrov I updated my post, now you can see rake routes results. The problem is that I get text only from `index` and not from `about` through standard get routes

Comment: What url are you using to access the about action on the pages controller?

Comment: @HashRocket localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to call the about action and you named it `about` in your routes.rb file, you have to point your browser to:

```
localhost:3000/about
```

You also have to set your `@title` variable to something in the `pages#about` action.

Comment: No problem. If you set the root to pages#about, you will go directly to the about page when you type in localhost:3000.